# My button is centered for iPhone 6 and 6 plus, but not for iPhone 5

Tags: swift, uibutton, uilabel

I do have autolayout on, but for some reason my center button isn't being centered for other phone sizes. I have constraints set and like I mentioned autolayout, so I'm somewhat confused. All other items are where they should be, buttons, other labels, etc. One specific label at the top is just off center for all models aside from iPhone 6.

Comment: Can you give some code?

Comment: @Rishi everything is done in the storyboard for this specific button. I'll add a gif of whats going on though.

Comment: add constraint horizontal center solve your prob.

Comment: @JAYRAPARKA Yeah those boxes seem to be greyed out. I'm trying to figure out why.

Comment: Can you show screen shot?

Comment: i'm adding new video just watch and apply but in your screen you need to set bottom space or you can set top space of bottom view to top view.

Comment: hope my answer will help to solve your prob.

Comment: @DharmeshKheni added up.

Comment: I am not sure what is wrong. Restart your Xcode and try again?

Comment: ya you right @DharmeshKheni there is some other prob. because my video and your answer  also work in all the devices.

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong you didn't add any constraint to your label that's why it is not at center.

Add this constraint for label.

[image]

Result for all screen:

[image]

Comment: It seems to be greyed out for me. Let me see what I can do.

Comment: This constraint are enough to set your label at center. Check the result in answer. :)

Answer (score 0):

i'm just adding video and setting constraints with rightclick on the outlet and selection done with left click

this is tested in all the device so just watch and apply you can solve your problem and if you want to arrange your view so you can add new constraints which is required otherwise you can set these 4 constraints set and execute.

just watch this video and setting your constraints

[you tube link to setting constraints in autolayout to centering button](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Uhg_jKQmyzY&feature=youtu.be)